# How to copy data from webbrowser to excel vb.net

Tags: vb.net, copy

I'm trying to copy the data from a webbrowser and past it into excel. 
My code is working, but I wanted to copy and past the format of the webbrowser. In other way, all the data will be present in one column.

```
    WebBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("SelectAll", False, Nothing)
    WebBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)
    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    Dim livro As Excel.Workbook
    Dim folha As Excel.Worksheet

    app.Visible = True

    livro = app.Workbooks.Add()
    folha = livro.Worksheets.Add()
    folha.Name = "a"
    folha.Range("A1").PasteSpecial()
```

Does anyone know how can I keep the format?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the HTML formatting to be in the Excel document? A little confused about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try: _WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml_